# Get the list of ADS groups of the currently logged in user using C#

Tags: c#, dns

I'm a beginner to programming,  I want to get  user's AD Group list using C#. If your answers  are in detail it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done this a few months ago, but don't have the code at hand. maybe i can check it out later, but this was approximately how it works:

```
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.Current;
foreach (GroupPrincipal gp in up.GetGroups())
{
    // do something with it, like reading out gp.Name
}
```

hope it helps. also, add the `System.DirectoryServices` assembly

Comment: Almost - you should use `UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.Current` to get the currently logged in user ...

Comment: PrincipleContext not needed?

Comment: No, there's no need for a `PrincipalContext` here.

Comment: I got what I need using above answer. I'm using this on VS installer class to check the group before installing. There it is not working its throw error "the server service is not started" on installation. Any Idea?

Comment: Idea: Installer might run as local-admin account, which is not in AD?